# Accidently posted annonymously, can the answer be associated with my account?

Tags: support, status-completed

I accidentally answered anonymously here:

["No such repository hgadmin" while installing mercurial-server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562218/no-such-repository-hgadmin-while-installing-mercurial-server-wtf)

Can I get that answer associated with my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag it for Moderator Attention and describe what you want done in the space provided.

Comment: @Randy: tell them you need "user [321887](http://stackoverflow.com/users/321887/randy-syring) merged into user [182111](http://stackoverflow.com/users/182111/randy-syring)" ... double-check the id's to make sure i got them right.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your help.  I went to do as you suggested, but the answer was already assigned to my user.